# The Apple light on my Macbook is damaged, could this damage the screen?

Tags: macbook-pro

My Macbook was hit  by my keys and crack the apple light on the back.

[image: Photo of Apple logo]

If I don't repair it, could this damage the sceen? The cover of Macbook is so thin that I really worry about this, but repair could be troublesome and expensive so I'd rather not have to fix it.

Comment: As long as you power on the MacBook and don't see any cracks or display issues on the screen, then you should be fine.

Comment: Currently there aren't any, and I'm using the Macbook well for 2 days. But since there are cracks on the light, would the sharp corner be threaten to the screen on back of it? I am now really feeling that the apple light is the weakest part on the Macbook.

Comment: I would say if it was going to cause any damage to the screen, it would have happened already. And with no screen problems after 2 days, it sounds like you shouldn't have any further breakage.

Comment: I broke the logo light today too...

Answer (score 3):

Essentially it is not a light but is simply a hole covered with a piece of plastic. LED which are used as your screen backlight serve as the actual light for the apple mark, so the apple mark is not lit on when the screen is not lit on.

In short, a crack in Apple mark will is not going to influence your Macbook in any way.

Comment: I agree - the cracks are so small, it looks like they won't cause the plastic to shatter or damage the back side of the LCD panel.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me... It should be okay because my MacBook worked fine after and never exhibited any issues on the screen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Keep in mind we are looking for *answers* that address the problem rather than commentary.  I edited your post to better reflect an answer.

Answer (score -1):

same thing happened to me and for me its not really a matter of having the crack hurt the screen its the fact the crack is there. it is very annoying to see the crack but I don't feel it's worth repairing.

If you really are worried, place some clear tape over the Apple to ensure that the plastic doesn't move further towards the LCD and damage it. Also, a protective case over the back of the Aluminum might help deflect any further pressure.

Since the cost to repair the plastic is basically as much as repairing the entire LCD - you might save your $$ until further damage happens.